# XNA Mono touch game - touch not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.ios, xna-4.0, tablet, monogame

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Express and the Mono SDK so I can do XNA game development.

I started reading about touch screen today and the Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Input.Touch namespace. I've put the following code into the Initialize() method of my main game class:

```
TouchPanelCapabilities tc = new TouchPanelCapabilities();

if (tc.IsConnected)
        {
            int i = tc.MaximumTouchCount;
        }
```

but tc.IsConnected returns false. I'm developing on a touch Windows 8 tablet so can't understand why it would return false. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initialising an empty structure. You need to call:

```
TouchPanelCapabilities tc = TouchPanel.GetCapabilities();
```

Then `IsConnected` should be true.